# How do I unlock the gold weapons?

Tags: alive-4-ever

In the iPhone game Alive-4-Ever, weapons like the GDE and GAK seem to be locked indefinitely.  Most guns have a price, but these are just locked.  How do I unlock them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- GAK - Beat 24 waves in Horde Mode
- M4 - Beat 16 waves in Horde Mode
- P90 - Beat 8 waves in Horde Mode
- GDE (Golden Desert Eagle) - Survive 10
  minutes in Survival Mode

Source: http://www.gamerevolution.com/cheat/ios/alive4-ever